# wpf mvvm custom control - call an action on the control

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've got a custom control that I'm using on a View in my MVVM Prism project - we've completely decoupled it so that the ViewModel does not have any access to the View.

From a command handler on my ViewModel I want to call a method on my Customer Control.

Whats the best way to hook it up?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can bind a property of the control to a property on the VM and register for the change of the control's property in the Control itself. That way you do not have to know the method of the Control in the VM.

Comment: Good idea - The data context of the control was being set - but I just added another grid outside that which then has the data context of the ViewModel and then I can tie everything up.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If it works, please mark my answer as the answer to your question so others can benefit.

Comment: Sorry, I did try and mark it with an answer straight away - but got that please wait 5 mins message ...

Comment: :) no problem. There should be a little time buffer to prevent mistakes and to get more answers.